# Firebase Database check if it's null value, doesn't work with DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

so I have a database where I search for products by barcodes. 
[image]

I wanted to have a check to see if the products are in my database

```
mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("ProductData");
productId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

public void searchProduct(String barcode){

    Query barcodeQuery = mFirebaseDatabase.child("Products")
            .orderByChild("barcode").equalTo(barcode);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    int price = ds.child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
                    int quantity = ds.child("quantity").getValue(Integer.class);
                    Log.d("DATABASE", name + "/" + price + "/" + quantity);  /// The output that I get is this: Neopraxam/25/1    and  Vazelina/250/1
```

That's how I search for the products by barcode.

```
searchProduct("123123123");

searchProduct("3232");
```

I have tried to add these methods to check if the value I'm trying to get is null:

```
if (ds.exists()){}  OR
if (ds.getChildrenCount() != 0){}
```

But I have seen that it doesn't even enter in the loop if the value doesn't exist. So I'm assuming that It's coming from the query.
So, how can I check if the query returns a null value because I used the method .equalTo(barcode) so I suppose that it should return a true or a false value

Comment: Have you tried to add failedListner to the call?

Comment: Hello, no, I haven't. So I guess that's how I should check if it's null or not ? @AliAhsan

Comment: no you can check if you are getting some error or not?

Comment: can you share the complete code plus firebase schema?

Comment: @AliAhsan as long as the requested products are showing how they should I assume that I don't get any errors because I have checked and it doesn't even get into the DataSnapshot loop

Comment: @AliAhsan yes, I canm where should I put it ?

Comment: update the question above

Comment: Are you calling `barcodeQuery` some point later?

Comment: @AliAhsan I have updated

Comment: @AliAhsan and I have searched for barcodes that doesn't exist but as I said, It doesn't even enter the DataSnapshot product. I use the query only there

Answer (score 1):

Issue seem to be with `onDataChange` signature as it contains `NonNull` annotation. To execute `onDataChange` body even for `DataSnapshot` null value , update the signature as follows

```
   ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        .
        .
        .

        }
```

**Note:** You should be using `SingleValueEventListener` instead of `ValueEventListener`

Comment: Actually, I have that in my code but I forgotten to put it. As I said, it's working as expected but the problem is that I could not find if the query is null or not

Comment: Well you've `@NonNull` annotation. So when snapShot is null, body will not be executed

Comment: Oh. So if I remove that, I’ll parse even null values. That’s good. Thanks

Comment: np updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in which DataSnapshot's [getChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getChildren()) method can return `null`:

> **Returns**
>
> - True if the snapshot contains a non-null value, otherwise false

What you should use to solve the issue, is DataSnapshot's [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#exists()) method:

> **Returns**
>
> - True if the snapshot contains a non-null value, otherwise false

So every time you perform a Query, check each item for existence using the above `exists()` method.

Besides that, your `searchProduct()` method can never return a value from the database. For more information, please see my answer from the following posT:

- [How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)

Comment: Thank you. I already solved. I removed the @nonull anotation and I checked dataSnapshot.exist() above the loop because I was checking ds.exist() inside the loop which was bad because there was no ds if there was no DataSnapshot to get childrens from